# Exercise on a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-independence

Hey I have a problem with this exercise. Can someone help me?

The erxercise is to show that there is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $f : \mathbb{Q}^2 → \mathbb{Q}^2$ with $f( \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} ) = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
4
\end{pmatrix}$ and $f( \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
5
\end{pmatrix}$. Determine $f ( \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix})$.Is $f$ bijective ?

So for the first I said that since the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent there exists a linear map. To find $f(\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix})$ is quite easy.

The problem is that I don't know how to prove that $f$ is bijective.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, if it isn't, then it has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Why not find the matrix for the transformation?

Comment: The determinant of the associated $2\times 2$-matrix is nonzero. So $f$ is bijective.

Comment: so I have that for $f(\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Therefore the matrix of the transformation is $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\det(A)\neq 0$ so is bijective. Right?

Comment: @Marco That is indeed a valid way to show that $f$ is bijective